# a service to provide Restangular objects

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I'm trying to make a service that will load persons from the server on demand. The first version looked like this:

```
services.factory('PersonServiceOld', function(Restangular, ErrorService) {
   var persons = [];
   var requesting = [];
   var get = function(id) {
       if (requesting[id]) {
           return persons[id];
       }
       requesting[id] = true;
       persons[id] = {'id' : id, 'photoName' : '0.png'};
       Restangular.one('persons', id).get().then(function(success) {
           persons[id].firstName = success.firstName;
           persons[id].lastName = success.lastName;
           persons[id].photoName = success.photoName;
       }, function(failure) {
           requesting[id] = false;
           ErrorService.serverError(failure);
       });
       return persons[id];
   };
   var reset = function() {
       persons = [];
       requesting = [];
   };

   return {
       getPerson : get,
       clearCache : reset,
   };
});
```

That way I get a reference to an object right away and it will be filled with data slightly after. It worked well... until I noticed that in another use case, I also want to request the address of a person like

```
var person = PersonService.get(id);
person.one(address).get().then(.......
```

but the objects returned from my PersonService aren't Restangular objects. So I tried something else:

```
services.factory('PersonService', function(Restangular, ErrorService) {
  var persons = [];
  var get = function(id) {
      if (!persons[id]) {
          persons[id] = Restangular.one('persons', id);
          persons[id].get().then(function(success) {

          }, function(failure) {
              ErrorService.serverError(failure);
              persons[id] = null;
          });
      }
      return persons[id];  // also tried: persons[id].$object
  };
  return {
      getPerson : get
  };
});
```

I hope somebody understands what I'm trying to do here and can give me a good pointer on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Check this <kbd>[**Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/DSXKetOPVcnVamqZtXmJ?p=preview)</kbd> for a complete example.

As Restangular returns promises, and your `get` function may be asynchronous or synchronous (in case you use your own cache), you need to create a promise for returning always the same type of object.

You can do it as described in the [Angular documentation for $q service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q).

So your `get` function may look like :

```
var get = function (id) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  if (store[id]) {
    deferred.resolve(store[id]);
  } else {
    Restangular.one('person', id).get().then(function (res) {
      store[res.id] = res;
      deferred.resolve(res);
    }, function (err) {
      deferred.reject(err);
    });
  }
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Then in your controller, for retrieving your data :

```
PersonService.get(475).then(function (person) {
    // stuff
}, function (err) {
    // err handling
});
```

Comment: how is that any different to just returning Restangular.one('persons',id) ? the way I use it in my controller is exactly the same :-(

Comment: it's because you want to have your own cache system ! :) in my opinion there is no need to create a service in your case, Restangular does the trick (and you can use the Restangular cache system : https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#can-i-cache-requests)